# Deleted a Perforce Checkpoint

Tags: backup, perforce

I made my first Perforce checkpoint and deleted the folder by accident. What should I do? Will creating a new checkpoint create a gap in the "chronology"? Can I make a checkpoint that is not reliant on previous checkpoints? Apologies about any ambiguity, I am new to Perforce server management. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just take a new checkpoint and you'll be fine.  Each checkpoint stands on its own as a snapshot of the database at the point when it was taken.  The journal files fill in the time in between checkpoints.

To recover the database from a disaster, all you ever need is the last checkpoint plus the current journal file.  If you've lost the last checkpoint somehow but you have an older checkpoint plus the intervening journal files, you can use the journals to catch up:

```
checkpoint.n + journal.n = checkpoint.n+1
```

Hence once you take a new checkpoint, everything before it becomes redundant from a recovery perspective.

When you create checkpoint.n, the current journal is rotated and becomes journal.n-1, filling in the operations between checkpoint.n-1 and checkpoint.n.  The current journal starts over from scratch recording everything that's happened since checkpoint.n.